# How can I use a background image instead of the IMG tag in html?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML with many of these kinds of links:

```
<a class="button" id="menu">
   <img width="16" height="16" src="/Images/control-double.png">
</a>
```

I created a sprite for these with all the images combined using

[spritegen](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/)

But when I look at this it seems like it's just for background as it gives an example:

```
.sprite-control-double{ background-position: 0 -396px; width: 16px; height: 16px; } 
#container li {
    background: url(csg-4febd28fe3aa3.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

How can I use a sprite with positioning for an image instead of a single  image?

Comment: is there a specific reason why you cant just use any other HTML element to display your sprite according to your desired position?

Comment: The code you've posted seems to do exactly what you're trying to do. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the "sprite" technique, then you don't need `IMG` elements within your anchors:

```
a.button {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(/Images/control-double.png);
    background-position: 0 -396px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

I added the `background-color` style because in some browsers the rendering engine will not show a background image if there is no background color.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. That's how sprites work, they're applied as the background for an element with its overflow set to hidden.

You should remove the `<img>` tag entirely and rely on the background of the `<a>` tag. The purpose of the sprite is to replace the need for non-semantic `<img>` tags.

Comment: But it seems a bit different for the img tag. Can I specify a background for an img and not use src? Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question. I've only ever used src with images.

Comment: The purpose of adding sprites is to remove the `<img>` tag altogether.

Comment: @Anne - *meagar* is absolutely correct. Apply all those styles to the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is all covered pretty well in the article linked from spritegens help page: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites